# No Talmud and Rambam fear of Indian idolatry?

Tags: talmud-gemara, rambam, avodah-zarah

India is mentioned in many ways in Talmud, and clearly our sages had extensive trade with India, for example Kohen Gadol's garments and Ketoret ingredients  see [Mishnah and Talmud dealing-with-indian-reality-150-500-ce](http://jppi.org.il/new/en/article/english-india-israel-and-the-jewish-people/english-table-of-contents/english-part-3-chapters/english-chapter-5-excursion-into-history-ancient-and-medieval-traces/english-mishnah-and-talmud-dealing-with-indian-reality-150-500-ce/#.WiZi7RmxXqA).

Rambam's brother David was a serious trader in India, and died in a shipwreck in the Indian sea [Maimonides' brothers](http://jewishstandard.timesofisrael.com/the-brothers-maimonides/) losing Rambam's money.

As our sages were very idolatry minded, and due to high resemblance of (*at least parts of*) Hinduism to idolatry, I would expect them either clarify their outlook on Hinduism or warn themselves and others of possibility of prohibited mixtures. As we know, Avoda Zarah disqualifies a mixture in any proportions, so one seed or one hair of sacrifices to Avoda Zarah would disqualify a whole ship full of the same sort.

I couldn't find though **a single mentioning of a doubt or abstention from such trade on the grounds of (even sofek) Avodah Zarah**.

Questions: Why is the serious doubt not mentioned?

Comment: Are not the many hindu names not idolatry because they are naming attributes, eg shanti is peace; prabuh is most powerful; so attributes of the One?

Comment: Maybe there just wasn't a market in human hair?

Comment: What is the difference between trade with India or any other pagan nation in ancient times (e.g Greece, Rome etc.), what makes India special?